# Adding an image texture to a material using python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to convert a script made for a tool called Noesis to Blender, so far I have gotten it to work, although I cannot find an alternative to this line of code for blender:
`material.setTexture()`

I would imagine there is something similar to this, but I can't find anything. So is there an alternative to change the material to an image texture and then assign an image to it, preferably without the use of nodes?

Edit: for the most part, I have fixed it, yeah, you have to use nodes. Thanks to everyone that helped out.

Comment: As of Blender 2.8x all materials are node based...

Comment: @brockmann essentially all I want it to do is change the "Base Color" to "Image Texture" then assign a texture to it
https://i.imgur.com/AHhT1Nn.png

Comment: Yeah, you would have to create an image texture node and plug it into the base color of the principled shader (explained in the linked post). If you still have issues, let me know...